# Updating objects in Concurrent Data Structures

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library, concurrent-programming

I would like to ask if it is possible to update an object inside a concurrent data structure. As of the moment, I have this code in my UI class:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Person)
Dim cancelToken As New CancellationTokenSource
Dim options As New ParallelOptions
options.CancellationToken = cancelToken.Token

Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() ParallelForEach(someOtherList, options, Sub(person)
DoWork(boss, myList)
End Sub),myList,cancelToken.Token,TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

Private Sub DoWork(ByVal boss as Boss, ByVal myList as List(Of Person)
dim person as new Person
person.Name = "Andy"
person.Boss = boss.Supervisor1

myList.Add(person)

' Display in gridview

Dim index as Integer = myList.FindIndex(Function(p) p.Name = "Andy")

myList(index).Boss = boss.Supervisor2

' Refresh Gridview
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest anything here to improve this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're asking about concurrent data structures, but your code doesn't have any, which means it won't work.

Comment: the question is that is it possible to update the object `person` inside the ConcurrentQueue, for example, and if so, how is it done.